# Check whether W is a T-invariant subspace of V

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ = $C([0,1])$

$T(f(t))$ =[ $\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx$]$t$

$W$ = {$f \in V $ : $f(t)$ = $at+b$ $for$ $some$ $a$ $and$ $b$}

I got $T(f(t))$ for $f(t)$ = $at+b$ is,

[ $\int\limits_0^1(ax+b)dx$]$t$ = $(a/2 + b)$$t$ ,which does not belong to $W$.

Hence $W$ is not a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$.

But my book says otherwise i.e. $W$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$.

I can't figure out where i went wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't $\left(\frac a2+b\right)t$ belong to $W$? It is of the form $ct+d,$ where $c,d\in\Bbb R$, yes?

Comment: oops ! i don't know what i was thinking. Thank you, got it !

Comment: You're welcome! We all have those "oops" moments from time to time.